Application Insights JS Client-Side: Change Sample Rate for certain events
I'm developing a Blazor WebAssembly app and I would like to see logs in Application Insights instance from it. To avoid unecessary amount of events, I have set Data Sampling to 50% on the AI instance.
Nevertheless, there are certain events that I want to track always and I'm trying to figure out how to enforce sample rate to be 100% for this.
Based on my research I did write a custom telemetryInitializer:
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer((envelope) => {
   envelope.sampleRate = 100;
});

The code above should turn all the trace events to 100 to my knowledge - but it doesn't.
I understand this could be misused by manipulating the JavaScript, but I'm curious if it can be achieved or not. I kind of run out of all my ideas.
Has anyone tried it and succeeded?
